# Apply anonymous functions to trees OCaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I have an anonymous function but I don't understand how it is applied.

This function works on trees, it creates a list of tuples within nodes and the sum of all the previous nodes `(node, sum_nodes)`.

This is the code :

```
let rec cost_leaf  = function
 Empty -> []
 | Tr(x,Empty,Empty) -> [(x,x)] 
 | Tr(x,left,right) -> List.map (function (y,c) -> (y,x+c))
 ((cost_leaf left) @ (cost_leaf right))
```

I got this : "This function is applied to a tree, defined as :

`type 'a tree = Empty | Tr of 'a * 'a tree * 'a tree` "

All ok.

"If empty then void list", just to check the return ok.

"If nodes below are empty return `(x,x)`", because I have to sum these values, ok.

"Apply this function to..." I don't understand what happens next.

`List.map` applies `(function (y,c) -> (y,x+c))` to all the elements of what? I imagine to the list that we will create in the next step but how? When I saw this I thought it was applied to the tree (because we have only this as input) but we can't apply `List.map` to a tree! (Also because the definition is clear : `int tree -> (int * int) list *)`).

Can someone explain me how this can works?

Comment: Yes, the `List.map` is applied to the list `((cost_leaf left) @ (cost_leaf right))`, which is passed as its second argument. (The first argument is the anonymous function.)

Comment: Aaaaah ok it's the second argument of List.map! Yeah you're right, the anonymous function is the predicate...Thank you. I'm new and these kind of functions are hard to read sometimes...

Comment: Yeah, the indentation is a bit weird, I wouldn't have expected the linebreak between those arguments